# Code Mirror GUI extension for RTF fields

Tags: gui-extensions, 2013-sp1-hr1

Is there any Code Mirror GUI extension to support RTF fields ? we have downloaded http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/new-version-of-sdl-tridion-2011-syntax-highlighting-gui-extension. However it is not supporting for RTF fields.

version of the product is 2013 SP1 HR1

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By Default codemirror supports templateviews as follow 
TemplateBuildingBlockView
PageTemplateView
ComponentTemplateView

you may need to modify CodeMirrorExtension.config and tridion-code-mirror-extension.js  to support Rich field.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, by just adding the right code to "Attach" to the source tab of the RTF field within a component. We have done this, so it is possible with the existing version that you have now.

The extension that we modified - I am also trying to make into an Alchemy plugin... but I am not sure if this will be sharable with the community yet (as it is for a client, and I will need to get permission)

/Brad